# Sort array of hashes by value of hash property in descending order preserving the initial order of hash

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of hashes in ruby. Each hash contains a key 'rating' which has an integer value. I want to sort this array by descending order of this value. Also the original order of hashes should be preserved. How to achieve this ?

This code performs the sort but does not preserve original order:
`new_results = results.sort {|a, b| b["rating"] <=> a["rating"]}` where `results` is an array of hashes.

If input array is:
`results = [ { "rating" => 6, "id" => 10699} , { "rating" => 3, "id" => 19985}, { "rating" => 6, "id" => 1029} ]`

I expect `new_results` to be:
`[{"rating"=>6, "id"=>10699}, {"rating"=>6, "id"=>1029}, {"rating"=>3, "id"=>19985}]`

NOTE: This is for explanation only. With above code, we get the expected result. But the order may not be preserved necessarily for other examples which I observed.

*Preserving the order* means if two hashes have same value for `rating` then they should be appear in the order in which they were present in input array.

Comment: It appears you want `results.sort_by { |h| -h["rating"] }`, but I don't know what you mean by, "...original order of hashes should be preserved." How can you sort an array without changing the order of its elements? Do you mean that a sorted array is to be returned but the original array is not to be modified? Where you say "Input hash is:" you mean "Input array is:".

Comment: @CarySwoveland ok, preserving the order means if two hashes have same value for `rating` then they should be appear in the order in which they were present in input array. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include the explanation you gave in your comment. Not all readers read all comments.

Comment: ok done. The description itself should make the question clear.

Comment: FYI this is called [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). And regarding _"With above code, we get the expected result"_ – what's the point of providing such example? Pick data which results in an unexpected / wrong result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
results = [
  { "rating"=>6, "id"=>10699 },
  { "rating"=>3, "id"=>19985 },
  { "rating"=>6, "id"=>1029 }
]

results.sort_by.with_index { |h,i| [-h["rating"], i] }
  #=> [{"rating"=>6, "id"=>10699},
  #    {"rating"=>6, "id"=>1029}
  #    {"rating"=>3, "id"=>19985}]
```

See the third paragraph of the doc [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for an explanation of how Ruby orders arrays. When Ruby orders `results[0]` and `results[2]` she compares `[-6, 0]` with `[-6, 2]`. Because the first elements of these arrays are equal (`-6`), Ruby compares `0` with `2` to break the tie, so `results[0]` is ordered before `results[2]`.

Note that when the method [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) has no block, it returns an enumerator. Here that enumerator is chained to [Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to produce another enumerator.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do the same with `sort` because it doesn't return an enumerator when called without a block (as opposed to `sort_by`)